# Add items to ObservableCollection<T> without blocking UI

Tags: c#, observablecollection

I'm trying to add items to `ObservableCollection<ProductSpecification>` from database table using `SqlReader`. Here is the code:

```
public void GetProductSpecification()
{
    ProductSpecificationList.Clear();

    using (var connect = Connection.Connect())
    {
        string query = "select * from ut_kst_specyfikacje_indeksow_test";

        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, connect))
        {
            try
            {
                using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        ProductSpecificationList.Add(new ProductSpecification()
                        {
                            //Here I am setting values of fields from reader[xx]. No parsing/converting errors in here.
                            //Also tried Dispatcher in here, but it throws exception "Invalid attempt to call MetaData while reader is closed"
                        });
                    }

                }

            }
            catch (SqlException e)
            {
                NLogger.logger.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This method is called in one of my `ICommand` commands binded to button. When I click this button, UI freezes for about 10 seconds (There are 45 000 records in `ut_kst_specyfikacje_indeksow_test`). In my opinion it's a little bit slow, honestly, I expected about 2 seconds.

As far as I know, `ObservableCollection` is bound to UI and cannot be updated from other thread than UI Thread. I've tried using `Dispatcher` but it occurs an Exception:

> Invalid attempt to call MetaData, while the reader is closed.

How to do this?

Comment: I would split the database call from the collection manipulation. You can make the method `async` and return Task<List<ProductSpecification>> (for instance) and then synchronously merge the results into your bound collection inside the method that `await`s the db call..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you are raising a notification for every addition to your `ObservableCollection`. This isn't going to work well for 45000 items

Note there are many solutions to this, however since you are clearing it every time, just create a new List and update it in one go. In fact unless you want to add and remove items you don't even need `ObservableCollection`. However, here is an example of updating in one go and being nicer to your UI

```
var list = new List<ProductSpecification>();

while (reader.Read())
{
    list.Add(new ProductSpecification()
                            {
                                //Here I am setting values of fields from reader[xx]. No parsing/converting errors in here.
                                //Also tried Dispatcher in here, but it throws exception "Invalid attempt to call MetaData while reader is closed"
                            });
} 

ProductSpecificationList = new ObservableCollection<ProductSpecification>(list);
```

Note : This is assumed the `ProductSpecificationList` raises a property changed event

Also consider making the whole lot `async Task`, and use `async` methods within `ExecuteReaderAsync` and similar

Add pepper and salt to taste